# Nearest points to image of isometric embedding

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

I have to prove the following:

Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces which are proper (i.e. closed balls are compact). If $f \colon X \to Y$ is an isometric embedding such that $f(X)$ is closed in $Y$, then for each $y\in Y$ there is an $x \in X$ such that $d_Y(y,f(x)) = \min_{x\in X} d_Y (y,f(x))$.

> Proof: Let $y\in Y$ be arbitrary and choose an $x' \in X$. Next, consider the closed ball $B$ with center $y$ and radius $r=d_Y(y, f(x'))$. Since $B$ is compact and $f(X)$ is closed, $B \cap f(X)$ is compact. Therefore, the continuous function
>   \begin{align*}
> d_Y(y, f(\cdot)) \colon B \cap f(X) &\to \mathbb{R}
> \\
> f(x) &\mapsto d_Y(y, f(x))
> \end{align*}
>   attains its minimum, i.e. there is an $x_\min \in f^{-1} (B)$ such that
>   \begin{equation*}
> d_Y(y,f(x_\min)) = \min_{x\in f^{-1} (B)} d_Y (y,f(x)).
> \end{equation*}
>   Also, for any $x \not\in f^{-1} (B)$ we have $d_Y(y,f(x)) > r \geq d_Y(y,f(x_\min))$ and therefore
>   \begin{equation*}
> d_Y(y,f(x_\min)) = \min_{x\in X} d_Y (y,f(x)).
> \end{equation*}

Is the proof correct? Could it be shortened?

EDIT: Following jJjjJ's comment, I wrote $B$ instead of $\overline{B}$ so that the closed ball is not confused with the closure of the ball.

Comment: You should be more careful because you are given that the closed balls are compact, i.e. $\{ x\ : d(x,y) \le r\}$ is compact for every $y$ and $r >0$. Anyway observe that, in general $ \overline{B(x, r)} \ne \{ x\ : d(x,y) \le r\}$. The proof is ok, but be aware that saying: let $\overline{B}$ be the closed ball, is a bit confusing.
You didn't use the hypotesis of isometry, probably the exercise wanted you to use the fact that compact metric spaces are sequentially compact, you can do this sort of proof taking $x_n \in X$ such that $\lim d_Y(y, f(x_n)) \to inf_{x \in X} d_Y(y, f(x))$

Comment: I don't understand why you say that in general $\overline{B(x,r)} \neq \{x :d(x,y)≤r \}$. Did you mean to write $\overline{B(y,r)} \neq \{x :d(x,y)≤r \}$? If so, isn't that how $\overline{B(y,r)}$ is defined?

Also, as you pointed out, $f$ does not have to be an isometry. This was not an exercise, but a part of another proof, of which I wanted to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Yes I meant that. Anyway in general $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$, thus $\overline{B(y,r)}$ is in general different from the closed ball. It's only a matter of notation, your reasoning is perfect but be aware of that

Comment: I see. I thought that $\overline{A}$ could also stand for the closed ball. I will change the notation and just write $B$ to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Comment: For example take $X= \{1,2\}$ with the discrete metric $d(x,y) = \delta_{xy}$. We have that $\overline{B(1, 1)} =\{1\} \ne \{ y : d(1,y) \le 1\}=\{1,2\}$